# While creating IP, IGMP packets using Raw Sockets, How to fill the hex value in those packets?

Tags: c, sockets, hex

I have one IP packet, which includes IGMP packet. I want to simulate this using RAW socket programming.
the checksum field of IP packet is e1c9, now how to assign this value in programming. I tried
iphdr->iph_chksum="e1c9";

also 
iphdr->iph_chksum=57801;

is the above thing right?

it is not working properly, please tell me the exact way?

Comment: 57801 is the hexadecimal value of e1c9

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work properly? give us more code so that we can help.

Comment: struct ipheader *iphdr =(struct ipheader *)buffer;  
          

iphdr->iph_ver=70;//given is 46(hexadecimal value)       
iphdr->iph_tos=192;//" c0        
iphdr->iph_len=52;//hexa value given34     
iphdr->iph_ident=0;          
iphdr->iph_flagoffset=64;//given 4000 in hex          
iphdr->iph_ttl=1;              
iphdr->iph_protocol=2;           
iphdr->iph_chksum="e1c9";         
iphdr->iph_sourceip=htons(atoi(argv[1]));        
iphdr->iph_destip=htons(atoi(argv[2]));        
iphdr->option1="9404";        
iphdr->option2=0;
I want output similar to what i have been given.. please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C syntax for hexadecimal values is `0xe1c9` in this case. you should however ensure that you are using the correct byte order, you will probably need to pass the value through `htons`

Comment: so will it be tried iphdr->iph_chksum=0xe1c9 ; ?? or iphdr->iph_chksum="0xe1c9" ;

Comment: @user572341: `iphdr->iph_chksum=htons(0xe1c9);`